# Get two buttons 50/50 width in my layout

Tags: java, android, layout

i've got a layout that looks like below. But ideally I want the buttons Save and Cancel to be 50% width each, next to each other. Can't quite seem to get them to work though.

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="-" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:width="100dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using a `RelativeLayout` for this design. You should be using a `LinearLayout`.

Something like this outline (very stripped-down):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation=vertical>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation=horizontal>
        <Button android:layout_width=100 /> <!-- Minus -->
        <EditText android:layout_width=0 android:layout_weight=1 />
        <Button android:layout_width=100 /> <!-- Plus -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation=horizontal>
        <Button android:layout_width=0 android:layout_weight=1 /> <!-- Cancel -->
        <Button android:layout_width=0 android:layout_weight=1 /> <!-- Save -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for `android:layout_weight="0.5"`. This only works with LinearLayouts, though.

So what you could do is add a LinearLayout that contains your two buttons and set the weights then.

Comment: Not in a `RelativeLayout`, he's not.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `LinearLayout`, inside the `RelativeLayout`, only for buttons, and give them the same `android:layout_weight` (1 and 1, 2 and 2, as you wish).